# How to use Tasker to answer a private number, play an audio file to the caller and hang up?

Tags: calls, tasker, auto-answer

I would like Tasker to answer any private number (without the audio playing through my phone's speaker) and play an audio file (an MP3 that says, "this phone does not accept calls from private numbers") and then disconnect the call.

Can someone help me set up a Tasker profile for this?

Comment: As an alternative you could do a search in Google Play for some call blacklist or call blocker app (they often include the option to block private number calls), I don't give you any names because I don't want to be downvoted.

Comment: @FranciscoAlvarado I have a call blocker app at the moment and it does its job. What I want is a little different: answer, play mp3, then hang up.

Answer (score 0):

Very few, if any, devices supports playing sound directly to the phone (voice) call audio stream.

Try playing a sound in Tasker using the Play Ringtone action to the Voice call audio stream, to see if your device support it.

Comment: how can I find out if mine does?